# laravel dusk facebook web driver and cookies

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, laravel-dusk

i was trying to login to a site with facebook chrome driver
and then visit another path of the website after login

login is successful but when I try to view another page 
it dont recognize my login
here is my code :

```
$process = (new ChromeProcess)->toProcess();
    $process->start();
    $options = (new ChromeOptions)->addArguments(['--disable-gpu', '--headless','--enable-file-cookies','--disable-web-security','--allow-file-access-from-files']);
    $capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome()->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

    $driver = retry(5, function () use ($capabilities) {
        return RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:9515', $capabilities);
    }, 50);
$browser = new Browser($driver);
        $browser::$baseUrl = 'https://example.com';
        $browser->visit('/login')
        ->type('username','1375344')
        ->type('password','23444')
        ->press('.login_btn');
        $browser->waitForText('welcome');
        $browser->visit('/statement/deposit/view');
        $browser->dump();
```

does laravel dusk and/or facebook driver has something like cookiejar?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$browser->loginAs(User::find(1));
```

Additionally you can look at

[Dusk Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/dusk#authentication)